# Accessing associative tables postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I'm working on an existing project that uses a postgresql database. This is my first time working with postgresql.

I have one major issue that is completely blocking me.

In the database creation script, I have the following lines:

```
CREATE TABLE "TA_cat_group" (
  cat character varying NOT NULL,
  group character varying NOT NULL
);
```

When I use a terminal and connect myself to psql, I can describe my database, by doing `\d`:

```
 List of relations
 Schema |          Name           |   Type   | Owner  
--------+-------------------------+----------+--------
 public | TA_cat_group            | table    | vit
 public | cat                     | table    | vit
 ...
```

I can then do `\d cat` in order to access the description of the cat table.

However, if I do `\d TA_cat_group` the following line appears:

```
 Did not find any relation named "TA_cat_group".
```

Because of this issue I'm uncapable of doing requests on this table... What could be the reason for this?

PS: I did a `\c vit` before, so I am connected under the right database, that doesn't seem to be the cause of my problem. Moreover, this schema is supposed to be public...

Comment: try; `\d "TA_cat_group"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the double quotes your table name is now case **sensitive**. `"TA_cat_group"` is a different name then `TA_cat_group`.

You need to use

```
\d "TA_cat_group"
```

---

I would however recommend to **never** use double quotes in your SQL statements to avoid having to cope with case-sensitive names.

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

---

Unrelated, but: you can't use `group` as a column name without enclosing it in double quotes because it is a reserved keyword. Your example `create table` in your question will result in:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"

The only way to avoid that error would be to use `"group"` instead of `group` - but that however would use those dreaded double quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much :) You just gave me the perfect answer to my problem!